# Basic understanding about Tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I am a newbie in R and is currently learning Tibble. Based on my course, tibble is a more streamlined data frame that prohibits changing the variable name. However, justnow when I tried to rename a tibble dataset on RStudio Cloud, I could rename its variable. Am I missing something here?

```
as_tibble(penguins) %>% 
  rename(new_island = island)
```

[Code output showed that the island column header has been changed to new_island](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af7A7.png)

Comment: Maybe your course details are outdated or it could be a typo.

Comment: If you check the description in `?dplyr::rename` -`.data - A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a tibble), or a lazy data frame (e.g. from dbplyr or dtplyr). See Methods, below, for more details.` which would be more uptodate (assuming you have the latest version of `dplyr`) than the course content)

Comment: @akrun It's a Google course that's released earlier this year. Even the Rdocumentation site (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/3.1.2) that's updated on May 2021 stated that Tibbles don’t change variable names or types, and don’t do partial matching.

Comment: It is always good to check the documentation of package i.e. `help("rename")` or `?rename` which gives more uptodate info

Comment: That's not what that means. It is referring to *automatic* renaming of variables, in situations like `tibble("11"="x")` vs `data.frame("11"="x")` . Though I take the point that it is not well worded if you didn't already know that happens.

Comment: "Tibbles don't change variables names" is very different than "Tibbles don't let you change variable names". (Though also strongly agree with thelatemail, for R newbies the wording should be changed or at least it should be contrasted wiith an example of how data frames do change variable names.)

Comment: @thelatemail Let me confirm if I get this right. Is tibble the one not allowing automatic renaming of variables? Cause when I ran both tibble("11"="x") vs data.frame("11"="x") on RS, I got a "x" column header for tibble, while for data frame I got a "X11". This showed that tibble indeed used whatever that is given in it's argument to form the table. But I couldn't reason why data.frame would change our column header. In which particular scenario would one favor the automatic changing of column header?

Comment: A *tibble* should have given you an `11` column name, while *data.frame* automatically renamed to `X11`. The reason why it renames is because `11` isn't a valid name in R (see `?make.names`. You wouldn't name a variable `11`, because it can make things totally confusing. E.g.: `\`11\` <- 12; \`11\` + 1` returns `13`. It's also worth noting that *tibbles* just change the default behaviour. You could always specify `data.frame("11"=1, check.names=FALSE)` for instance.